# How can I interchange the values of two arrays while preserving memory as much as possible?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

Two arrays are to be interchanged with their values, I am seeking methods to do it without using third array. How could it be solved? I saw some arithmetic methods (as shown below) to do it for integers, but couldn't sort out my problem with string arrays.

```
int a[350]={350 values};
int b[350]={350 values};
for(int i=0;i<350;i++)
{
    a[i]=a[i]+b[i];
    b[i]=a[i]-b[i];    
    a[i]=a[i]-b[i];
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of one of your "problem strings"?

Comment: I already fixed your question here, but for future reference, note that you can format code on Stack Overflow by simply indenting it with 4 spaces.

Comment: What's wrong with the above code?  It uses O(1) memory, which is about as good as you're going to get.

Comment: are you assuming all entries in the array are integer values?

Comment: Are you asking for a *better* way to do it than you've shown, or do you want to know how to do the same thing but with *string* variables instead of integers?

Comment: What are the constraints? That is is one temp variable too much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to iterate over the array, you don't need a new array; just one temporary variable will suffice, and you can reuse it each iteration.

If any new memory allocation is forbidden, then you could use the arithmetic or XOR solution, as long as the data type is integral.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 350; ++i)
{
    a[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    b[i] = a[i] - b[i];    
    a[i] = a[i] - b[i];
}
// or
for(int i = 0; i < 350; ++i)
{
    a[i] ^= b[i];
    b[i] ^= a[i];
    a[i] ^= b[i];
}
```

Finally, you can always just swap the array pointers!

```
object[] a;
object[] b;
object[] temp;

temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why use any ridiculous tricks? Can't you spare a single `int` temporary?

```
for(int i=0;i<350;i++)
{
    std::swap(a[i], b[i]);
}
```

or

```
std::swap_ranges(a, a+350, b);
```

Note: on my machine, the XOR trick typically takes twice as long as just using a single temporary variable for the swap.

Answer (score 0):

IF the arrays are integral, you can uses the xor trick:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 350; ++i) {
    a[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
    b[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
    a[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
}
```

no temporaries needed

Comment: To show the two-variable case:  A1 = A xor B, B1 = A1 xor B = (A xor B xor B) = A, A2 = A1 xor B1 = A xor B xor A = B.

Comment: Won't using ++i cause a[0] to be skipped, then overflow at a[350]?

Comment: no, the end clause is only run at the end of each loop, so i++ and ++i yield the same results.  ++i is just habitually preferred (i++ will create a temporary variable to hold a result, whereas ++i does not need the temporary)

Comment: compilers are very good at optimizing out temporaries, so any recent C or C++ compiler will just treat both `++i` and `i++` as a simple increment... as long as `i` is a built-in of course.

Comment: @Matthiew M. It's easier to be consistent :)  Also i find it really strange that K&R decided to write i++ instead of ++i everywhere

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can use bit xor for with pointers (I assume that strings are `char*` or `wchar_t*`). But really I don't think that one variable is bad for you and it will be better just to use `std::swap`.

Answer (score 0):

Even better:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 350; ++i)
{
    a[i] ^= b[i];
    b[i] ^= a[i];
    a[i] ^= b[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the author's question is swap the array not using a third array. So I think just use one variable is enough.

```
int tmp = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < 350; ++i )
{
    tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = b[i];
    b[i] = a[i];
}
```

why bother use some xor operations?

Comment: I think your last line should be `b[i] = tmp;`

Comment: because the question is "How can I interchange the values of two arrays while preserving memory as much as possible?" :)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not work: it illustrates a simple problem actually, that many have stumbled upon.

Algorithms' descriptions do not, in general, take into account the finite memory representation that computers have.

In particular here, `int` can only hold so many bits, and thus the addition may result in an **overflow**, which is undefined behavior (on x86, it wraps around, but on other processors it might trigger a hardware exception).

There are two correct (and simple) solutions to exchange two `int`:

- `int tmp = lhs; lhs = rhs; rhs = tmp;`, also known as `swap`
- `lhs ^= rhs; rhs ^= lhs; lhs ^= rhs;`, also known as the XOR trick

Both are obviously applicable in case of arrays.

Another solution, more efficient, would be to swap the arrays themselves.

```
std::swap(a,b);
```

*Note: if the arrays are statically allocated, it's not possible to swap them directly, but you can perfectly only use pointers to the statically allocated arrays and thus swap the pointers*

**Caveat:** objects that already have a reference to the arrays will not be notified of the swap, in this case you have no other choice than swapping their content.